# Using GetObject() with vb6.0 in a dll

Tags: dll, vb6

i'm using a method to get all usb extern insert in a pc. I use a function write in a vb6 and i create a dll. Now i want use the dll in a c++ program but i have an error about the getObject() function. Can i use getObject() in a dll write in vb6?
This is the code of the function

```
Public Function GetUsbDeviceList() As String
    Dim ComputerName As String
    Dim wmiServices As Object
    Dim wmiDiskPartitions As Object
    Dim wmiDiskPartition As Object
    Dim wmiDiskDrives As Object
    Dim wmiDiskDrive As Object
    Dim wmiLogicalDisks As Object
    Dim wmiLogicalDisk As Object
    Dim Vol As Object
    Dim strFound As String
    Dim Query As String

    ComputerName = "."
    Set wmiServices = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=Impersonate}!//" & ComputerName)

    strFound = ""
    ' Get physical disk drive
    Set wmiDiskDrives = wmiServices.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive where InterfaceType = 'USB'")
    For Each wmiDiskDrive In wmiDiskDrives
        'MsgBox ("Disk drive Caption: " & wmiDiskDrive.Caption & vbNewLine & "DeviceID: " & " (" & wmiDiskDrive.DeviceID & ")")
        'Use the disk drive device id to find associated partition
        Query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='" & wmiDiskDrive.DeviceID & "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"
        Set wmiDiskPartitions = wmiServices.ExecQuery(Query)

        For Each wmiDiskPartition In wmiDiskPartitions
           'Use partition device id to find logical disk
           Set wmiLogicalDisks = wmiServices.ExecQuery("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='" & wmiDiskPartition.DeviceID & "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition")
            For Each wmiLogicalDisk In wmiLogicalDisks
                'MsgBox ("Drive letter associated with disk drive = " & wmiDiskDrive.Caption & wmiDiskDrive.DeviceID & vbNewLine & " Partition = " & wmiDiskPartition.DeviceID & vbNewLine & " is " & wmiLogicalDisk.DeviceID)
                 Dim DatiUnita As Scripting.FileSystemObject
                 Set DatiUnita = GetObject(, "Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                Set Vol = DatiUnita.GetDrive(DatiUnita.GetDriveName(wmiLogicalDisk.DeviceID))
                strFound = strFound + wmiLogicalDisk.DeviceID + "," + Vol.volumename + "," + wmiDiskDrive.PNPDeviceID + ";"
            Next
        Next
    Next

    GetUsbDeviceList = strFound
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
Set DatiUnita = GetObject(, "Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

to

```
Set DatiUnita = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

(Alternatively, you could use

```
Set DatiUnita = GetObject("", "Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

i.e. an empty string, not to be confused with an empty `Variant`.)

Comment: +1. See also the VB6 help on [`CreateObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262700(v=vs.60).aspx) and [`GetObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445016(v=vs.60).aspx)